# Install app without put it on Android Market

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play

How can i install my application from eclipse to my mobile (Galaxy) without put it on Android Market?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't use eclipse, but once you build your app and sign it into an 'apk' you can simply connect the device via USB to your development machine and install it via a command line (terminal) window with the command: `> adb install my_app.apk` See the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) for all the ADB options. It's worth your time to learn about ADB

Comment: Thank you but can you explain more. how can i sign it into 'apk'? and why should i learn about ADB options? Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

you can connect your phone wuth usb cable and run it.  http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Answer (score 0):

you can find your file.apk and install it on your device  from your workspace > Solution name >bin

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to generate apk file manually,

1. Settings > Applications > Development > USB Debugging set it on.
2. Connect your phone via USB cable.
3. Run your app.